# Back Stack Management Issue

Tags: android

I have an activity that manages a lot of fragments using .replace().  I am having a problem when I use the back button.  Here is an explanation:

Activity adds f1 -> 
f1 is replaced by f2 (add to backstack) -> 
f2 is replaced by f3 (no backstack addition)

press back button

f1 appears
click button to replace f1 with f2, both f1 and f2 are on screen - overlapping

I read a lot of questions and answers on this issue, and this is what I found:
when f1 is replaced by f2, the transaction is added to the backstack.  So when back is clicked, it removes f2 and adds f1.  However, f2 has already been replaced and therefore cannot be removed.

I am not sure if this is my issue or not, because it seems like when I click back, f3 is being removed.

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Thanks!

edit: Any ideas? I can give more info if that would help

edit: just tested adding all transactions to the backstack, and clicking back multiple times to get back to f1, and the problem is gone.  So it seems like this is the issue.  How would I go about fixing it?

Comment: It would help if you showed the code that transitions from one activity to the next.  Of particular interest is whether or not you call "finish()" on the current activity before launching the next one.  Could you post this code?

Comment: You may want to give this a read to get a better understanding of the back stack: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html.

Comment: I am using fragments.  So the code is: 

`ViewFragment vfragment = new ViewFragment();
         vfragment.setRetainInstance(true);
         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, vfragment, "View");         
                  fragmentTransaction.commit();`

Comment: and a addToBackStack Call for the first replace